# show $p$ is divisible by $(x^2 +y^2 +1)$

Tags: number-theory

Show that, for any prime $p$, there are integers $x$, and $y$ such that $p$ is divisible by $(x^2+y^2+1)$    Can you show me what to start with? do I prove $p$ is divisible by $x^2$ and $y^2$ separately?

Comment: $p$ is prime so it shouldn't be divisible by anything except 1 and $p$.  Are you sure you have the statement correct?

Comment: You have it backwards, $p$ divides $1 + x^2 + y^2.$ This is a step in the proof that every prime is the sum of four squares.

Answer (score 3):

Take $x=y=0$, then $x^2+y^2+1=1$, then $p$ is divisible by $x^2+y^2+1=1$.

Comment: lol${}{}{}{}{}{}$